# How do I enable Failed Request Tracing in IIS 10.0 on Windows 10 development PC?

Tags: trace, iis-10

How to I enable Failed Request Tracing in IIS 10.0 on my Windows 10 dev pc?

I can find instructions for IIS7  and IIS8.5 (see http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85) but doesn't seem to be available in IIS10.

According to above instructions there should be a link to "Failed Request Tracing" under "Configure" in the Actions pane - but see in screen shot it is clearly not there:
[screen shot of IIS Actions pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8rtH.png)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The instructions should work exactly the same since the UI has not changed. Make sure that you install Failed Request Tracing, for that run 
**OptionalFeatures.exe** and make sure that Tracing is enabled in the Internet Information Services->World Wide Web Services->Health and Diagnostics.

Comment: This is now also available for install via the Web Platform Installer (WebPI) by searching "IIS: Tracing" Download link: https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: because this answer wasn't very helpful if you don't already know where to find that .exe, the instructions on this page are useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests/

Comment: @matao Thanks that link is helpful. You should make this an answer!

Comment: @matao the exe is on the PATH

Comment: @JaniekBuysrogge "'optionalfeatures' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.", run from one of our dev web servers. Because you need to jump through the hoops in my link to install the darn thing. Not sure where you got the idea that it's just floating around on the PATH from...

Comment: @matao That .exe simply opens the "Turn Windows features on or off" dialog. where optionalfeatures.exe ->
C:\Windows\System32\OptionalFeatures.exe

Comment: @JaniekBuysrogge ok I see what the issue is. On my Windows 7 desktop optionalfeatures.exe is in that location, but when I check our (old) 2008R2 web server it's not. environmental factors yay ;-)

Comment: You can also run `Install-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Tracing` in PowerShell.

Comment: Neither this answer nor any of the others address the fact that in IIS 10 there is no Configure link, as the OP asked. [Even when I am positive the feature is installed](https://imgur.com/a/D0ICLI3).

Answer (score 34):

You can also add this feature by going to Start -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> Health and Diagnostics.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 16):

You can enable the tracing feature using this PowerShell command (Running as Administrator)

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Tracing
```

Comment: Install-WindowsFeature : The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.