# ASP.NET website never comes up, how can I debug it?

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, freeze

We moved our ASP.NET application from 1 server (Win 2012 R2, IIS version 8.5.9600.16384) to another server (Win 2016, IIS version 10.0.14393.0).
In the new server, when I go to the website, it is just hang and the website never comes up.
How can I debug this issue ? 
How can I tell where the website is hanging at ?
Thank you.

Comment: It won't "just hang" forever - eventually something will timeout. Have you identified if the problem is the TCP connection not being made? Is the `w3wp.exe` host for your application running? What's listed in IIS Manager's Application Pools window?

Comment: Have you looked in "Event Viewer" -> "Windows Logs" -> "Application" on the server?  Also, [How do I enable Failed Request Tracing in IIS 10.0 on Windows 10 development PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33146750/1115360)

Comment: I do see w3wp.exe in the Task Manager. In  IIS Manager's Application Pools, the application uses Integrated Managed Pipeline Mode, and for identity, it uses a service account which has a Modify access to the application folder.
How do I identify if the TCP connection is being made or not ?

Comment: "Event Viewer" -> "Windows Logs" -> "Application" doesn't show anything

Comment: I suggest you could try to use DebugDiag tool to capture the hang dump and then you could sue debugdiaganalysis to analysis the dump logs. Then you could find some useful information in it. Details about how to use debugdiag to capture the dump, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pfedev/all-the-ways-to-capture-a-dump#external-tools). Details about how to use debug analysis, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/02/01/analyze-a-memory-dump-using-the-debug-diagnostic-tool/).